# Commerce Kickstart new products aren't showing under manage products

Tags: commerce

I'm working with the Commerce Kickstart 2 release and I'm starting to figure out how this works, but I'm having one major issue.  I've created a new Product and content type, created taxonomy to populate it up into the menu etc. But I can't get the new products to show in under the "manage products".  It populates onto the new page under the new menu item so it's there.  I've re-indexed the Search API, and nothing happened.  I've taken a look at the views that are being indexed and it looks fine too.
Has anyone else had this issue - if so were you able to resolve it?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you added a field to the content type relating it to the commerce product type?

Comment: yes, I have the product types fields such as price, image, sku etc. in the content type and they're pulling fine.

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head though!  I went back through all the settings on the sample products and made sure that my Content type setting and fields and the Product type settings and fields matched the samples and now it's populating on the product page.  I'm not sure which setting made the difference but it's working now!!!  Thank you!!

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted :)